# How to convert/decode a pandas.Series of mixed bytes/strings into string or utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8

I would like to solve the problem in two possible cases:

1. Where I don't know whether the Series of strings is going to be `UTF-8` or bytes beforehand.
2. Where the strings in a `pd.Series` are mixed bytes and `UTF-8/.

Which I'd guess would have the same solution.

Currently for:

```
b = pd.Series(['123', '434,', 'fgd', 'aas', b'442321'])
b.str.decode('utf-8')
```

Gives `NaNs` where the strings were already in UTF-8. Or are they automatically ASCII? Can I give the `error` parameter in `decode` so that the string remains "undecoded" where it's already in UTF-8 for example? The docstring doesn't seem to provide much info.

Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Alternatively, is there a string method in pandas like `.str.decode` which instead just returns a True/False when a string is `bytes` or `UTF-8`?

EDIT:

One option I can think of is:

```
b = pd.Series(['123', '434,', 'fgd', 'aas', b'442321'])
converted = b.str.decode('utf-8')
b.loc[~converted.isnull()] = converted
```

Is this the recommended way then? Seems a bit roundabout. I guess what would be more elegant is really just a way to check if an `str` is bytes on all the elements of a Series and return a boolean array where it's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will definitely slow things down for a large Series, but you can pass a ternary expression with a callable:

```
>>> b.apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, bytes) else x)                                                                                                                                                                                      
0       123
1      434,
2       fgd
3       aas
4    442321
dtype: object
```

Looking at the source for `.str.decode()` is instructive - it just applies `_na_map(f, arr)` over the Series, where the function `f` is `f = lambda x: x.decode(encoding, errors)`.  Because `str` doesn't have a "decode" method to begin with, that error will become NaN.  This happens in [`str_decode()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d1accd032b648c9affd6dce1f81feb9c99422483/pandas/core/strings.py#L1734).

```
>>> from pandas.core.strings import str_decode                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>>> from pandas.core.strings import _cpython_optimized_encoders                                                                                                                                                                                              

>>> "utf-8" in _cpython_optimized_encoders                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
True
>>> str_decode(b, "utf-8")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, '442321'], dtype=object)

>>> from pandas.core.strings import _na_map                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> f = lambda x: x.decode("utf-8")                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> _na_map(f, b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, '442321'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem still open in [git](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22613)

Caused by the line

> ```
>   except (TypeError, AttributeError):
>          return na_value
> ```

Fix adding `fillna`

```
b.str.decode('utf-8').fillna(b)
Out[237]: 
0       123
1      434,
2       fgd
3       aas
4    442321
dtype: object
```

Comment: The only thing is that this will *mask actual errors due to encoding*.  If you have a Latin-1 bytes that cannot be decoded as Utf-8, it gets replaced by its original when that may be unintended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both were very instructive and useful, and I wasn't sure which to put as accepted. Also thanks for bringing up the git Issue, it does seem like something that would be useful to fix.